# Artisan packages error

Tags: laravel, package

I'm having some trouble with artisan/packages.. I've added a package to my composer file and ran `composer update` and an error was returned:

`PHP Warning:  require(/home/xxx/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/public_html/artisan on line 16`

I can see that require path is incorrect, my structure is like so:

```
/home/xxx/bootstrap
/home/xxx/app
/home/xxx/vendor
/home/xxx/public_html
```

I hadn't changed any of the paths and everything seemed to work out of the box with this structure, basically removing the public folder and pushing everything up a directory.

I've opened up Artisan tried a couple of paths that kept failing so i've changed them to absolute:

`require '/home/xxx/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

It seemed to work from here on, but at the end of the process got another error:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

[RuntimeException]
Could not scan for classes inside "app/commands" which does not appear to be a file n or a folder
```

Rather than continue to mess it up i thought now would be a good time to clear it up, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why are artisan inside public_html folder?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using php 5.3 or higher.

Run php -v

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty "app/commands" folder, fixed the issue for me!